# TableView combobox display issues after scrolling

Tags: java, javafx

I'm facing a display issue after scrolling. Some of the combo boxes in my `movieSubtitleTableColumn` cells that are supposed to be empty, they are filling with the same items and values from other combo boxes. Also the combo boxes that were filled correctly before the scrolling they retain their correct items and values even after the scrolling. 
So, the problem is happening only in the empty ones for some reason.

**Controller:**

```
@FXML
private TableView<Movie> moviesTableView;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Movie, String> movieTitleTableColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Movie, Subtitle> movieSubtitleTableColumn;

private ObservableList<Movie> movieList;

private void setupTableView(List<Movie> movieList) {
    this.movieList = FXCollections.observableList(movieList);
    moviesTableView.getItems().addAll(this.movieList);
    movieTitleTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getMovieFile().getName()));
}

private void populateSubtitleChoiceBox() {
    if (!movieList.isEmpty()) {
        movieSubtitleTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue().getMovieSubtitle()));
        movieSubtitleTableColumn.setCellFactory(col -> {
            ComboBox<SubtitleInfo> combo = new ComboBox<>();
            combo.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            combo.setConverter(
                    new StringConverter<SubtitleInfo>() {
                        @Override
                        public String toString(SubtitleInfo subtitleInfo) {
                            if (subtitleInfo == null) {
                                return null;
                            } else {
                                return subtitleInfo.getFileName();
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public SubtitleInfo fromString(String s) {
                            return null;
                        }
                    });

            TableCell<Movie, Subtitle> cell = new TableCell<Movie, Subtitle>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Subtitle subInfo, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(subInfo, empty);
                    if (empty) {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    } else {
                        if (subInfo != null) {
                            combo.getItems().setAll(subInfo.getSubtitleList());
                            combo.setValue(subInfo.getSubtitleSelected());
                        }
                        setGraphic(combo);
                    }
                }
            };

            combo.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) ->
                    cell.getItem().setSubtitleSelected(newValue));

            return cell;
        });
    }
}
```

**Models:**

```
public class Movie {
    private File movieFile;
    private Subtitle movieSubtitle;
    private BooleanProperty movieSubDownload = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    //getters setters
}

public class Subtitle {
    private List<SubtitleInfo> subtitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    private SubtitleInfo subtitleSelected;
    //getters setters
}
```

Before calling the populateSubtitleChoiceBox(), i update my movieList like this:

```
for (Movie movie : movieList) {
   //do stuff
   movie.setMovieSubtitle(subtitle);
}
populateSubtitleChoiceBox();
```

**Screenshots:**

[Before scrolling (Correct Display)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH9xL.png)

[After scrolling (Comboboxes that were supposed to be empty they are not anymore)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ipg8.png)

EDIT:
Currently i've masked the problem by setting graphic to null:

```
        TableCell<Movie, Subtitle> cell = new TableCell<Movie, Subtitle>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Subtitle subInfo, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(subInfo, empty);
                if (empty || subInfo == null || subInfo.getSubtitleList().isEmpty()) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    combo.getItems().setAll(subInfo.getSubtitleList());
                    combo.setValue(subInfo.getSubtitleSelected());
                    setGraphic(combo);
                }
            }
        };
```

Although i still don't know how to properly fix it and why is that happening. Please let me know if you need any other part of my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When your cells are reused (e.g. during scrolling), the calls to the `updateItem(...)` method will repeatedly call

```
combo.getItems().addAll(...);
```

on the same combo box, so you will just add more and more elements to the combo box's items list. You should replace all the items each time, so just replace that method call with a call to `setAll(...)`:

```
combo.getItems().setAll(subInfo.getSubtitleInfoObservableList());
```

Comment: James i have tried that already. It's still behave as before. What else could be wrong? Actually, the combo boxes that are supposed to be empty, they get their items from the other correct combo boxes

Comment: @DeckardCain Not sure then. You will probably need to write a [MCVE] and edit your question to include it.  There is nothing else obviously wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: I'll try my best. Please excuse me for my question structure.